# Expected utility theory (Lottery notation)

Tags: microeconomics, utility, expected-utility

A wheel of fortune has outcomes $S=\left \{ 1000,100,50,20,0 \right \}$ as money prices. A consumer has the preferences

$$20\sim \left ( \frac{2}{100}\cdot1000 \oplus \frac{98}{100} \cdot 0 \right )$$
$$50\sim \left ( \frac{15}{100}\cdot1000 \oplus \frac{85}{100} \cdot 0 \right )$$
$$100\sim \left ( \frac{45}{100}\cdot1000 \oplus \frac{55}{100} \cdot 0 \right )$$

What does this notation mean? I figure that the direct sum is just showing that the percentage for winning $1000$ in the first equation is $2/100$ and $98/100$ for $0$. But what does the $20$ denote? Is this some utility and how would that be read with the indifference sign in front of it? Never seen the notation like this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\left(\frac{2}{100} \cdot 1000 \oplus \frac{98}{100}\cdot 0\right)
$$
is the lottery where you get $1000$ with probability $2/100$ and $0$ with probability $98/100$.

The expression
$$
20 \sim \left(\frac{2}{100} \cdot 1000 \oplus \frac{98}{100}\cdot 0\right)
$$
usually says that the decision maker is indifferent (in terms of preferences) between taking the lottery and having $20$ for sure.

Comment: So say that the consumer face 2 wheels. the first wheel the consumer wins $1000$ with probability $1/4$, $50$ with probability $1/4$ and $20$ for the rest. The second he wins $1000$ with probability $1/5$, $100$ with probability $1/4$ and nothing for the rest. How do I determine from the preference which he chooses from the $3$ equations?

Comment: (just to take a look at the usage of the preferences)

Comment: This should be a separate question.

Comment: @mathstudent23 you assume rationality (empirical evidence is against such an assumption) and substitute for $50$, $20$ and $100$ using the indifferences you have been told to turn the two wheels into equivalent $1000$ & $0$ lotteries

Comment: @VARulle I agree. Up now.

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by substitute in this context?

Comment: @mathstudent23 $\left ( \frac{1}{5}\cdot1000 \oplus \frac{1}{4} \cdot 100 \oplus \frac{11}{20} \cdot 0\right ) \sim$ $\left ( \frac{1}{5}\cdot1000 \oplus \frac{1}{4} \cdot  \frac{45}{100}\cdot1000 \oplus \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{55}{100} \cdot 0 \oplus \frac{11}{20} \cdot 0\right )$ or something like that, which you can simplify

Comment: @Henry I am not sure on why this lottery was written but wouldn't the simplified one be $\left ( \frac{1}{5}\cdot 1000\oplus \frac{70}{100}\cdot 1000 \oplus \frac{80}{100}\cdot 0\oplus \frac{11}{20}\cdot 0  \right )$

Comment: @mathstudent23 It can be simplified, but your fractions do not add up to $1$.  Instead $\left(\frac{5}{16}\cdot1000  \oplus \frac{11}{16} \cdot 0\right)$